# Space between rows Rmarkdown

Tags: pdf, r-markdown

Instead of having 10 rows of equation explanations I want to reduce it to 5 so that I on one line have two explanations with sufficient space between them so that it looks nice on the PDF.
When I put them on the same line now I cant seem to force the space between them and it appears on the PDF with only a single space.

Any suggestions?

```
The formula for a three asset portfolios variance is:  

\begin{equation}
  \sigma_p^2 = w_a^2 \sigma_a^2 + w_b^2 \sigma_b^2 + w_c^2 \sigma_c^2 + 2w_aw_b \sigma_{ab} + 2w_a w_c\sigma_{ac} + 2w_b w_c \sigma_{bc}
\end{equation}

Where:

  $\sigma_p^2$ = The portfolios variance 

  $w_a^2$      = The weight of asset a            

  $\sigma_a^2$ = The variance in asset a         

  $w_b^2$      = The weight of asset b           

  $\sigma_b^2$ = The variancde in asset b        

  $w_c^2$      = The weight of asset c

  $\sigma_c^2$ = The variance in asset c

  $\sigma_{ab}$= The covariance between asset a and b

  $\sigma_{ac}$= The covariance between asset a and c 

  $\sigma_{bc}$= The covariance between asset b and c
```

Comment: This looks like a LaTeX question.  What does it have to do with RMarkdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to enter LaTeX code at the markdown

```
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}[l]
\sigma_p^2 = The portfolios variance\\
w_a^2      = The weight of asset a\\
\sigma_a^2 = The variance in asset a\\
w_b^2      = The weight of asset b\\
\sigma_b^2 = The variancde in asset b\\
\end{aligned}
\qquad\qquad
\begin{aligned}[l]
w_c^2      = The weight of asset c\\
\sigma_c^2 = The variance in asset c\\
\sigma_{ab}= The covariance between asset a and b\\
\sigma_{ac}= The covariance between asset a and c\\
\sigma_{bc}= The covariance between asset b and c\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
```

[image]